# What is a more accurate translation of the title of Legend of the Galactic Heroes?

Tags: japanese-language, legend-of-the-galactic-heroes

Several people have mentioned to me that the title of *Legend of the Galactic Heroes* is based on a rather "interesting" translation. What would be a more accurate translation of the original title (銀河英雄伝説 *Ginga Eiyū Densetsu*)? I've also heard that it is based on a German title, that was then translated to Japanese, and then to English - I don't know if that is true, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Ginga Eiyuu Densetsu*** is a series of Japanese novels written by a Japanese person, and is not, to the best of my knowledge, materially based on any previously-existing work.

---

The 110-episode OVA series (which is probably what most viewers are familiar with) was given the alternate title "Heldensagen vom Kosmosinsel". I don't speak German, but various discussions on the internet suggest that "Heldensagen vom Kosmosinsel" is not valid German. A look at [de.wiktionary.org](http://de.wiktionary.org/) suggests that "Kosmosinsel" is not even a word, or perhaps is a compound noun meaning "cosmos island" (which is not idiomatic for "galaxy"; that would be "Galaxie").

Given this, it looks like the producers of the OVA figured that it would look cool to have a faux-German title ([in Gothic font, too!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm3Bv.png)), ran "銀河英雄伝説" through Babelfish (or maybe through some dude who'd had a year of German at university), and got out "Heldensagen von Kosmosinsel". It's probably the case that the translation went Jap -> Ger (badly) and Jap -> Eng, rather than Ger -> Jap -> Eng.

---

I'm not sure why you've been hearing that that "Legend of the Galactic Heroes" is an "interesting" translation of 銀河英雄伝説 (*ginga eiyuu densetsu*), though. 銀河 *ginga* means "galaxy"; 英雄 *eiyuu* means "hero"; and 伝説 *densetsu* means "legend".

It's a bit contracted to omit particles, as titles often are, but the meaning is clear - this is a *densetsu* about the *ginga eiyuu*s, i.e. a *legend* about *galaxy heroes*. Hence, ***Legend of the Galactic Heroes***.

---

Note: in the comments, [@Krazer correctly points out](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5816/what-is-a-more-accurate-translation-of-the-title-of-legend-of-the-galactic-heroe/5817#comment6666_5817) that an alternate parse of *ginga eiyuu densetsu* is as "*eiyuu densetsu* about the *ginga*", i.e. "Heroic Legends from the Galaxy". Now that I think about it, I'm not really sure which parse is actually better, in terms of the show.

Comment: If we draw from both sources we can infer that 銀河(Milky Way/Galaxy) 英雄伝説 (heroic [legendary] tales) can also potentially mean: "Heroic Tales/Legends from (the) Milky Way/Galaxy."

Comment: @Krazer Good catch. I've incorporated that into the answer.